# Unicode string columns in monospace

Tags: text, unicode, icu

I'm writing a pretty-printing combinator library, which means that I'm laying out tree-structured data in a (probably) monospaced font. To lay it out, I need to know how wide it's going to be. I'd like to do this without involving any particular rendering engine or font—chances are, it's going to be dumped to the terminal most of the time. Is there a correct way to do this?

From my reading, I’m thinking that grapheme clusters are one reasonable approximation. Is there a way to deal with characters that are typically fullwidth? What else do I need to worry about?

Comment: There isn't a good answer for this. the East Asian Width property in Unicode is not sufficient, see the proposed update in https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr11/proposed.html#Scope … the actual answer depends on the terminal emulator.  But yes, grapheme clusters can help, especially considering emoji sequences (which again vary by implementation)